# Objective C: Can the Countdown timer Picker be used as a hour/min picker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, datetimepicker, countdown

I was wondering if I can directly use the standard countdown picker as an hour/min picker e.g. user can select the number of hours and minutes as parking duration etc...

Basically I want the to use the countdown picker interface without the counting down functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is perfect for this.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806):

> The UIDatePicker class implements an
>   object that uses multiple rotating
>   wheels to allow users to select dates
>   and times. iPhone examples of a date
>   picker are the Timer and Alarm (Set
>   Alarm) panes of the Clock application.
>   You may also use a date picker as a countdown timer.

You can get pretty creative with it too.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I managed to implement it as a hour/min picker :)